# import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker - cannot find package

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans

I need to use this package in OSGI bundle

```
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;
```

When I try to compile the code with Netbeans this package is not found. Do you have any idea What repository I need to add in order to use this package?

Pest wishes 
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar file you need for that `import` to work is:

```
org.eclipse.osgi*.jar
```

And it *should* be in your plugins directory. If you're just starting out, I highly recommend you go through [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html) tutorial. It will give you a step-by-step breakdown on how to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the class from here:
    org.apache.felix.framework-[version].jar

A very vice tool for finding packages is here:
    http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java